# How to create handy post message in telegram via bot on php

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to create handy message like in this [channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVmH6.png)

All I've done is just here code sample

```
    $bot = new \TelegramBot\Api\Client('xxx:yyy');
    $bot->sendMessage("@dtsautocom", "<a href='https://dts-auto.com/{$passanger_car->main_photo}'>{$passanger_car->name}</a> \n{$passanger_car->year} год, {$passanger_car->price} $, пробег - {$passanger_car->mileage} км \nТелефон продавца: {$passanger_car->phone}", 'HTML');
$bot->run();
```

I wrapped image link to a tag and I get image, but this is not good solution and I've got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkFIa.png). I want to create like in the first link above. How did they do this? Can anyone give me please code sample of how to do it in right way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They used [sendPhoto](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) method with `parse_mode` set to `HTML` and formatted photo caption.

For your API library it should be:

```
  $bot->sendPhoto("@dtsautocom", "https://dts-auto.com/{$passanger_car->main_photo}", "{$passanger_car->name}\n{$passanger_car->year} год, {$passanger_car->price} $, пробег - {$passanger_car->mileage} км \nТелефон продавца: {$passanger_car->phone}", null, null, false, 'HTML');
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am going to check it as soon as possible and i will response.